# Email address is auto suggested in first name field

Tags: javascript, html

Saved email address is auto suggested in `"First name"` field of `"Sign Up"` form. When I click the first name field, saved email address is coming below the first name field for selection. I have searched and found that if we include a fake `firstname` field with `'display:none'` before the original first name field the issue will be resolved. But it doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post the code that isn't working the way it should. Have you added any autocomplete attribute to the inputs?

Comment: Yes. I have added "autocomplete=off". This is my input field for firstname <input type="text" ng-model="firstname" name="uName"/>. I have added another input field above this field with "display:none" property (i.e) <input type="text"  name="userName" style="display:none"/>. If I remove "name" attribute from "firstname" field it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `autocomplete="off"` attribute to text box.

Ex: `<input type="email" autocomplete="off" />`

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I have understood that you don't want email auto suggested you want name over there...

I would suggest to check type for the input field...

```
<input type="text" name="fname">
```

else I would have failed to understand you...

Comment: I dont want the name to be auto filled in my name field. Just I want to restrict the auto suggestion of email address in name field. "type" is text only.

Comment: autocomplete="something" add this in your input then **'<input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="nope">**
'  try this

Comment: Yes. Already I have added this. But it is not working. If I remove the "name" attribute from my input field it is working.